# Angular Lazy-loaded Modules sharing internal flows

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, lazy-loading, router, ng-modules

I am developing an application which is using ion-tabs and im trying to share some specific internal flow [NgModule at the moment] from feature_2 with feature_1.
This would look something like this. In feature_1 i have a button, when i click that button, i launch a flow from feature_2, but i stay on tab1. Whenever i click back from that page i just launched I'm back on tab_1. The problem Im facing is that whenever i try to navigate from app/tabs/tabs1 to app/tabs/tab2/some_internal_page i switch tabs and that path app/tabs/tab2/some_internal_page becomes the landing path of app/tabs/tab2 instead of its intended page.

The example routes are:

```
path: 'tabs',
component: TabsPage,
children: [

  {
    path: 'tab1',
    loadChildren : () => ...Module1
  },
  {
    path: 'tab2',
    loadChildren : () => ...Module2
  }
]
```

Where the modules themselves have their own internal routes. Example for tab1 when Module1 is loaded:

```
path: '',
component: LandingPage,
children: [

  {
    path: 'internal',
    loadChildren : () => ...Module3
  },
  {
    path: 'internal_two',
    loadChildren : () => ...Module4
  }
]
```

Some things i tried:

1. Using ion-nav and exposing a specific flow using a service from a feature module. Where that service using a modalController launches some specific component. This is kinda tedious because i have to manage my own nav stack, i can't use router to navigate etc.
2. I tried using an external path such as app/modal, which would mimic the features that are under app/tabs/. This helps with the navigation but because of lazy-loading im obviously having separate instances of the services required for that specific feature. (I can remove the services from providers and user providedIn: 'root') but that sounds overkill since all features need to make everything available as root even if required only for that specific feature module?

Is there a way for me to share internal NgModules of features lazy loaded within ion-tabs flow with any other feature? Navigate though their flows but stay on the current tab and once done be able to navigate back?

Comment: what do you mean when you say "launch a flow from feature_2"?  Are you routing to a different url? Are you displaying a modal?

Comment: As an example, when feature_2 is lazily loaded lets say it has a flow of 2 pages to add a user. feature landing page [click a button] > set user info > add work information and save, navigate back to landing page. At this moment with ion-nav yes im treating it as a modal flow of 2 pages. But if navigating within that feature then it would be app/tabs/tab2/user_details/work_details as an example. i want to be able to share the /user_details/work_details flow with other tabs i.e tab1.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @BizzyBob in the ionic documentation they do mention that developers should not be trying to navigate from tab1 to tab2 without user interaction and that if two tabs want to display the same component they should each have internal paths that display that same component. Another idea i had from that is something like app/tabs/tab1/modal and app/tabs/tab2/modal where 
{
  path: 'modal'
  loadchildren() => SomeService.loadAnyModule()
}
in his case loadAnyModule() is a static function that can return any module specified by any feature library. In my case NgModule of user_details page.